# Algorithm best placement of nodes in hierarchical graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, hierarchical-data, hierarchical, hierarchical-trees

I am looking for building a hierarchical graph dynamically & programmatically.

a graph like this:
[image: example]
<sub>(source: [graphviz.org](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/unix.png))</sub>

I don't know how to place the nodes in a good way to avoid collisions.

Any idea of an algorithm I could use?

Comment: Please specify your exact question

Comment: well, i would like to find coordonates for each nodes

Comment: The topic of *graph layout algorithms* has been extensively researched and there is much published literature, also programs and libraries.  Hit your favourite search engine.

Comment: java or javascript Dante. i ll take a look HPM